# Swift build fails: target might include it's own product

Tags: cocoa, swift

Has anyone run into this issue? I was experimenting with porting an existing obj-c app to Swift, and after quite a few successful builds the project will no longer build and immediately gives the error: Unable to run command 'CompileSwift normal' - this target might include its own product. Along with many other 'target might include it's own product errors'.

**What I've Tried:**

- Checking Target Dependencies: There is nothing listed as a target dependency in Build Phases.
- I've tried completely deleting the product folders, and have went through all the files multiple times but with no luck.
- If I simply replace the Swift files with the old obj-c files it builds fine, no errors at all.
- Restoring to a snapshot prior to any Swift modifications results in building as normal, but even if I add a brand new Swift boilerplate file and bridging header, then click build, it fails with the same errors.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a bug to me. You can file a bug report at [http://bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: Not sure if you found another answer, but it seems that this results from a bug in the Xcode 6 beta. I removed it from applications and redownloaded it and that seemed to fix my project. However, once I picked the same target it was broken again :(

Comment: I've pretty much resigned to the fact that this is a bug in the xcode beta, hopefully it'll be resolved in the next seed.

Comment: I had this same issue, and I'm not *exactly* sure what the cause was, but it turned out I had an import referencing a file that no longer existed. I got the actual error to show up by disabling code signing then re-enabling it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue. I couldn't work out exactly what was causing it, but realised the same code would build find on a different Xcode 6 install on a different machine.

I solved it by deleting my cached builds, etc, in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode`, while Xcode is not running. "Clean" alone from within Xcode didn't do it.

You should find that when you re-launch Xcode your app will build fine.

Comment: Yup, looks like every once in a while the Swift compile process just goes insane.

Comment: For those who don't know how to clean out cached crap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4
Or in short, just remove everything in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 5):

Deleting my app target from "Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources" worked for me. *(Somehow it was being included for bundling?)*

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem. In the objc-to-swift bridge header I imported a header of an objc class, *which* also imports swift-to-objc header. There was a cycle of imports and this could be the reason Xcode complaint.

I think for now it is best to avoid such *cyclic* importing between swift and objc. You might want to check that out.